# cannot access ActivityCompatApi23 class file for ActivityCompatApi23 not found

Tags: android, gradle, onesignal

Hi i added one signal libraries in to my project and suddenly when i run the project a lots of error shows up in my code which in top is

```
Error:(66, 8) error: cannot access ActivityCompatApi23
class file for android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23 not found
```

here is my dependecies

```
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'
compile 'se.emilsjolander:StickyScrollViewItems:1.1.0'
compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.1.0'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'org.hashids:hashids:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'

compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1"

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.1'
compile 'com.adjust.sdk:adjust-android:4.12.0'
compile 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'
```

Comment: You are using two different versions of Support library

Comment: can you tell me more specific i don't see that @EpicPandaForce

Comment: Upgrade all of your libraries at first place. Like all play-services library to 15.0.1, all android support libraries to 27.1.1, compileSdkVersion to 27 and firebase libraries to whatever latest. And then check if error persists

Comment: Never use x.+ kind of versions in Gradle. It is strictly not recommended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using different versions for support libraries

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1' <- here you are compiling 26.0.0-alpha1
// ...
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
// ...

compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+' <- this one can be different from 26.0.0-alpha1 since it compiles versions greater than 26, i.e. version 27.1.1
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
// ...
```

So when gradle tries to build your project, it finds two different support library versions.

I guess you can fix your problem with upgrading all your support libraries to version 27.1.1. Like this

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
// ...
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v27.1.1'
// ..
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
// ...
```

Also, as parekhkruti26 said in comments, never use 'X.+' for versions since it can cause problems like this and its not recommended. I guess android studio itself shows a warning when adding dependencies using 'X.+'.